# My site doesn't display certain images

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, drupal, pictures

after a system upgrade, certain pictures aren't displayed in my Drupal installation. I notice that, for instance, some jpeg are visible while other are not (the extension being for both jpeg, all lower case).

I'm working on Ubuntu, locally, and I upgraded the system from 9.10 to 10.04 LTS, so also Apache and PHP where upgraded too.

Any thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check that the access rights are consistent.**

Make a note of the "rwx" privileges for owner, group and world on a file that is displayed and one that isn't. If they are different then make the them the same - i.e. the value of the file that is displayed.

Also check that the directory/folder access rights are consistent.

**Check that the pathnames to the files are correct.**

Case shouldn't matter, but double check anyway. Check that there are no unescaped spaces or other special characters. Either rename the files or change how they are referenced.

**Double check the colour mode of the files.**

Some graphics packages can write CMYK jpgs as well as RGB ones. Not all browers (eg. Internet Explorer) can display CMYK jpgs. You'll need access to Photoshop or similar to check this. Resave the files in RGB mode.

It's unlikely to be this given you say that the problem has only started since an upgrade, but I've included it for completeness.

Comment: I'm going to check access rights and pathnames, but for the colour mode it would be strange, though, because I'm using the same firefox and the same google chrome where a few minutes before the system upgrade the same pictures were displayed.

Comment: @dag729 - I realised that and updated my answer. Don't forget to check directory access rights - it could be all images in a particular directory that are affected.

Comment: Thank you ChrisF! Your troubleshoot is the best I could think of, also if the error was fixed in an other way. (you helped me also on SU: so thank you twice as much! :P )

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Ubuntu to 10.04 will have upgraded PHP from 5.2 to 5.3, which some Drupal modules have a real problem with.  The update to Drupal may have included bugfixes related to this issue, or it may simply have cleared one of the caches which Drupal uses.

Make sure nothing else has broken with this upgrade, because you will come across issues.  We're pinning PHP at 5.2 in order to keep Drupal sites working.

Comment: At the moment, after some hours of testing, the only issue I came across, was the one aforementioned: I was using the Zina module, and the issue appeared to be strictly related to its code. Upgrading that module seems to have fixed the visualization problem. Anyway I always fear these distro upgrade...the bugfixing could be stressful! I'll look forward for other problem, then. :D

Answer (score 0):

An update to Drupal fixed the strange images behaviour, although I don't understand what happened...